# how to get attributes using PHP SimpleXML (in mediawiki-api-xml output)

Tags: php, xml, mediawiki-api

im trying to get a List of Mediawiki-Articles into my php-script. I am using MediaWiki's `api.php` with xml output. 
My dummy-data look like this:

```
<api>
   <query-continue>
       <categorymembers cmcontinue="page|474c495353494552454e|162"/>
   </query-continue>
   <query>
       <categorymembers>
           <cm pageid="297" ns="0" title="Add move"/>
           <cm pageid="116" ns="0" title="Ascanio-Spread"/>
           <cm pageid="193" ns="0" title="Doublieren"/>
           <cm pageid="358" ns="0" title="Down-under"/>
           <cm pageid="274" ns="0" title="Einwegmuster"/>
           <cm pageid="227" ns="0" title="Elmsley-Count"/>
           <cm pageid="130" ns="0" title="Falsch abheben"/>
           <cm pageid="144" ns="0" title="Falsch mischen"/>
           <cm pageid="565" ns="0" title="Filieren"/>
           <cm pageid="148" ns="0" title="Forcieren"/>
      </categorymembers>
   </query>
</api>
```

I am looking for all the "titles" in the `cm`-Containers.

My Script looks like this:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($mywiki);
 foreach($xml->cm[0]->attributes() as $a => $b)
 {
   echo $a,'="',$b,"<br>";
 }
```

Which is intended to give my all attributes of the first cm-container. But that wont work, I get error:

```
Call to a member function attributes() on null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Before posting a question, **please be explicit about your own debugging efforts**. You should have checked this:

```
var_dump( $xml->cm[0] );
```

Next, you might wish to do something like this:

```
$xml->query[0]->categorymembers[0]->cm[0]
```

Go along the path down to the node in question.